# How to remove the shared with or email to everyone buttons

Tags: 2013

Is there a way to hide the "Shared with ..." or at least the user-names and emailaddresses from specific user groups?

I'd like to hide at least the users which have access to a SP2013 site from the users self, because we have data privacy concers about that list.

I uploaded a picture of the button i was talking about (German Language Version):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPDN6.jpg

Answer (score 3):

You could get the HTML reference and hide it like this

```
<style>#Ribbon\.Documents\.Copies-LargeMedium-0 { display:none; }</style>
```

Be careful this works for IE, if your user use other browser you have to write other CSS option.

Comment: Well, this would work, but it's not what i want to use (as long as there might be another method) since it is only hidden from the view. I'd really prefer a way which removes the right to see the contents of the underlying list. But nevertheless your answer is helpful.

Comment: another way is create a custom action for the ribbon that override the default... but I think hide the button is easy and quick :)

Comment: BTW. this is not from the ribbon i think - it's behind this little gear-icon

Comment: do you have an image?

Comment: I uploaded an image.

Comment: ok you could do that with CSS as well

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent users from viewing the option "Shared With", you need to make changes to the Permission level.

Go to Settings -> Site Settings -> Site Permissions -> Permission Level. 
Select the permission level and uncheck option "**Browse User Information - View information about users of the website**".
Once done login with the user who has been granted that permission level and then try to access "Shared With". The user will get access denied error.

Comment: This here Looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [Security Trimming](http://www.codeovereasy.com/2013/04/security-trimming-the-sharepoint-ribbon/).

The link is to a tutorial that shows how to do it in SP 2010, but it should apply to SP 2013 just as well. You'll still need to identify which permissions roles should be allowed to see it (there's a link to MSDN's list of SP Permissions in the article).

I might test this at work sometime (we are only just testing SP 2013 right now) and if I do, I'll write up a more detailed tutorial.

Comment: Do you know about a list of delegateControls in SP2013?

Comment: I can't say that I'm an expert, but I have had some exposure to using DelegateControls. Is there a question you have about it?

Comment: I try to remove the "Shared with.." from the user menu, but i could not find any hint to delegate controls up there. But perhaps i have to dig deeper.

Comment: Upon further research, I've found that the DelegateControls can't really modify that menu option. The reason is because DelegateControls are almost like placeholders where you can inject code into the page at runtime without having to actually modify the master page.  I'm sorry I mislead you in this. I've updated my answer. I've only recently gotten some free time so I'll be looking into Security Trimming, and I recommend that you do so as well.

Comment: Thanks for your time anyway! DelegateControls will help me with another issue :)

Comment: I unfortunately have not had any time to further test this. Work has picked up for us, so SP2013 is going to the backburner. Good luck with finding your solution!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove only "EMAIL EVERYONE" across the site collection then you can use the below style either in you master page or custom css file.

```
.js-sharing-fullListDialogCommandEmail
{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Regards,
Arjun

Comment: Essentially I want to remove the whole useless "shared with ..." menu - and I really hate CSS visibility hacks, but thanks for the info anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this tidbit of information from MS's [SP 2013 Overview of Sharing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/fp123606.aspx) video (audio):

> There is one important thing to note: the Sharing feature depends on using email for some of the notifications so you must configure the outgoing SMTP server and the From Address in Central Admin. If you don't do that, only site owners will be able to use any of the Sharing features. They won't be displayed for anyone else.

While I cannot recommend this because of other features that depend on the email configuration (eg. Workflow email notifications) and it doesn't seem like a great idea to purposely leave something unconfigured, it could potentially be a solution for a fraction of SP users who do not require email actions from their sites.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the Shared with... class, put in the master page:

```
.js-callout-sharedWithList {
     display: none !important;
}
```