# Prevent users from seeing "Shared with"

Tags: sharing, external-sharing

I was under the impression that if a user does not have permission to see user details and count permissions they would not be able to see the "Shared with".

I'm not really a fan of hiding it using CSS/Javascript, so any other suggestions are more than wellcome!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortinately that's not possible. You could remove the option to see User Information, but it won't remove the button. Your only option is the ugly implementation of `display: none;`.

Reference: [How to remove the shared with or email to everyone buttons](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/66420/how-to-remove-the-shared-with-or-email-to-everyone-buttons)

EDIT:

> Go to Settings -> Site Settings -> Site Permissions -> Permission
>   Level. Select the permission level and uncheck option "Browse User
>   Information - View information about users of the website". Once done
>   login with the user who has been granted that permission level and
>   then try to access "Shared With". The user will get access denied
>   error.

Comment: I'm ok with the button being there if the actual list is empty, but that does not seem to be the case :-(

Comment: @MortenK Does a "Access denied error" work for you? See edited answer

Comment: Yup that would be fine - if only that worked. I have made a custom permission, granted the external users the permission level. But they are still able to browse all users any item they have acces to are shared with!

Comment: Thinking about it a bit more, could it be caused by the user also having the "Limited access" permission as i grant the user direct access to a library? Scratch that - I grant the users my custom permission to site level.

Comment: The limited access only apply to the site itself when you break inheritance. I don't think that's the answer to your question... https://en.share-gate.com/blog/what-is-sharepoint-limited-access

Comment: It's really odd. I have a user group with a set of external users. This usergroup has my custom permission (without "Browse User Information - View information about users of the website"). When checking a user in the group they don't have access from anything else. Yet when visiting the site they can see all the users any item has been shared with...

Answer (score 0):

I had a heureka moment with a bit of help from @4rchit3ct

Making a custom permission and removing the "Browse User Information - View information about users of the website" from it. This isn't the whole story though, you would also need to make sure"Limited-access user permission lockdown mode" is activated.

Now it works as expected!