# Sharepoint Online - How To Prevent Users From Seeing Who A Document Is Shared With

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions

On a SharePoint Online site, if a user clicks the ellipses next to a document name, they get a pop up that shows who the document has been shared with.

[image: Document Shared With ..]

How can I prevent users from seeing who a document is shared with?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To prevent users from seeing who a document is shared with, you can remove their access to the "Manage Permissions" permission level. This will prevent them from accessing the "Shared With" pop-up and other permission-related features on the document.

To do this, follow these steps:

1. Go to the document library where the document is located.
2. Click on the gear icon in the upper-right corner and select "Library Settings".
3. Under "Permissions and Management", click on "Permissions for this document library".
4. Find the group or user you want to restrict and click on the drop-down menu next to their name.
5. Select "Remove User Permissions" and click OK.

Repeat this process for all the users or groups you want to restrict. Note that this will only remove their ability to view the "Shared With" pop-up and other permission-related features on the document. They will still be able to see the document name and metadata, and they will still be able to view the document itself if they have been granted access.

Answer (score 0):

You want to hide "Shared with" from other users. As far as I know this should not be possible, I found a user with the same problem as you, check this thread:[Prevent users from seeing "Shared with"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/252508/prevent-users-from-seeing-shared-with)